# Как вывести модальное окно при переходе с определенной страницы?

Tags: javascript

Есть главная страница сайта index.php. Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на главную страницу, выводилось модальное окно id="modal", но только при условии перехода со страницы add.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не хотите использовать `query` параметры, то можете воспользоваться [Document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)